# Style sheet not linking to document

Tags: html, css

Very simple task that doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I am getting no results when I view in the browser, my styles are not being applied to my HTML. My style sheet is in the same folder as main document with the html. I am previewing the code in chrome on a localhost. Not sure what is going wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="meta description placeholder example.">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css">
    <title>Web Start</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="main">test</h1>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

My styles are placed in a separate document called mystyles.css

```
<style>
  .main {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is it in the same folder as html file?

Comment: Yes as stated above

Comment: did you use `<style>` tag in your css file? if yes, then remove it

Comment: check the route and i try removing the tags <style></style>

Comment: @Tushar perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test in one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="meta description placeholder example.">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .main {
      color: blue;
    }
    </style>    
  <title>Web Start</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="main">test</h1>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or as Tushar said: remove `<style>` and `</style>` from your css file

Answer (score 0):

Where is the location of your CSS file?
For your code to be correct, they need to be in the same folder, otherwise you will need to tell the computer which directory to look in by using ../ for each directory back, and then you need to tell it where to look after, ie.

```
../STYLES/main.css
```

Answer (score -1):

u just need to remove the   opening and closing style tag as it predefined with the link tag.
update your mystyles.css

Comment: @Tiw I think it *is* an answer, just a poor one, check the question

Comment: that was my first answer to any question 
relax guys

Comment: remove <style> and </style> from your css file

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: sure, will keep this in my notice